# Is there a way to ignore a non threadsafe module in perl?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to find a way to ignore a module within a certain portion of code so that I can use the threads module with the non thread safe module Win32::OLE.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::OLE;

#Do some OLE stuff

#unimport Win32::OLE
use threads;

my $exec_command = threads->create(sub{});
$exec_command->join();
#reimport Win32::OLE
```

Comment: You will have to run it in its own process that doesn't use `threads`. Why did you delete your previous question?

Comment: I decided to re ask here since I figured using non threadsafe modules with threads is a common mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `Win32::OLE` on your main thread, unless you create **all** other threads first. You can, however, use the module in a child thread.  Do note `require` instead of `use` here.

```
my $ole_thread = threads->create(sub {
    require Win32::OLE;
    # do OLE stuff
});
my $result = $ole_thread->join();
```

[ citing http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=595491 ]

This same method may work on other modules that are not threadsafe. But you should use care to only use the module from a single non-main thread.

Comment: I have a module imported in main which can't be modified that uses Win32:OLE. If I require that module within a new thread I assume I won't be able to use functions defined inside that module in main right? Could I still export the functions that module defines but not the Win32:OLE functions to a global scope?

Comment: @TheAschr: If you're talking about the `InHouseModule` from your deleted question that `uses` dozens of other modules then you should do all you can to get that changed. It's very bad practice and will make all your Perl programs larger unnecessarily. There will also be multiple compatability problems such as the one you're experiencing here.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to do that. The act of loading the `Win32::OLE` module itself is what causes the thread-unsafe behavior, not the fact that the functions are imported.

Comment: @Borodin: I believe it uses all of them though. The module is over 12,000 lines. Is there a better way to handle importing them?

Comment: @TheAschr: That's also unmanageably big. You should at least split it into chunks with related functionality. You might want to rewrite the functions so that they `require` and import from the modules they need.

Comment: @Borodin: Unfortunately the guy who wrote the module left like 10 years ago and management is scared to let anyone touch it because of legacy issues.

Comment: @TheAschr: Well at least you can be grateful that he's gone. Management need to get a proper test suite written for that module and then allow it to be amended and split up. It's mad to rely on a single gigantic core library that no one may ever change.